# Where to find the distance between vehicles in Omnett Project?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to obtain an exact distance between vehicles in the Omnett++ Vehicle Project so I can make a graph but I failed at finding the distance.

Is there anywhere I can find/modify the distance between vehicles? or somewhere I can get the changes in the distance between them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veins 5 represents all vehicles on the simulation canvas, using their x/y position on a 2d map as the coordinates of where to draw the icon. See the OMNeT ++ documentation on getdisplaystring for how to obtain a module’s graphical representation in a way that is independent of how Veins works.